# How to Add Button Edit and delete in JFXTable View and How to edit row to the SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, javafx, sql-update, tableview

hi guys i've two questions ! 
i am using NetBeans 8.2 and SceneBuilder for gui

t've a JFXTableView field by data from SQL i want to add a column Action contain two buttons edit and delete for each row

and i want to edit rows and update data in my sql , i use this for update but i don't know how to implent them

```
 public static void modifierElement(int id, String nom, int prix, int qnt) {
    try {
        String query = "UPDATE element SET element='" + nom
                + "', prix=" + prix
                + ", quantite=" + qnt
                + " WHERE id=" + id;
        cnx = connecterDB();
        st = cnx.createStatement();
        st.executeUpdate(query);
        System.out.println("Produit bien modifié");

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

}

public static Connection connecterDB() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        //System.out.println("Driver oki");
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/taxiphone";
        String user = "root";
        String password = "";
        Connection cnx = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        //System.out.println("Connexion bien établié");
        return cnx;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

i tried to use this

```
TableElement.setEditable(true);
    clmID.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
    clmELement.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
    clmPrix.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
    clmQuantite.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
```

it change just instance it didnt't saved in my SQL Database thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

For action column you can fill each cell by using `HBox` (containing delete and update buttons). For each button in `HBox` you can set listener and perform database operations accordingly

```
actionCol.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Person,HBox>, ObservableValue<HBox>>() {

        @Override
        public ObservableValue<HBox> call(CellDataFeatures<Person, HBox> currentRow)
        {
            Button updateButton = new Button("update");
            Button deleteButton = new Button("delete");

            updateButton.setOnAction(e->{
                //Database operation to update record goes here
            });

            deleteButton.setOnAction(e->{
                //Database operation to deleted record goes here                
            });



            ObservableValue<HBox> s = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(new HBox(updateButton,deleteButton));


            return s;
        }
    });
```